# Eclipse hangs on Refresh DSLD scripts

Tags: eclipse

Using eclipse Build id: Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0).
It performs an operation: `Refresh DSLD scripts` and never ends - simply hangs.
I restart and it hangs again.
Try new workspace still hangs.

Comment: Eclipse 2019-09 is more than three years and 13 releases behind. Please upgrade. Please make sure the software you use is up to date before asking.

Comment: @howlger appreciate that but I am constraint on that decision.

Comment: Not telling your technical constraints makes your question an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).